# Azure RM Template. Deploy copy VM with unique secret from Key Vault

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault

I would like to be able to create VMs amount of which I specify via parameters (achieved by copy) with different secret for each VM (ex. secret1 for VM1, secret2 for VM2, etc.) Here is a basic example of copy VM template:

```
    {
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
    "numberOfVMs": {
      "type": "int",
      "defaultValue":  1,
      "minvalue": 1
    },
    "vmAdminUserName": {
      "type": "string",
      "minLength": 1
    },
      "vmAdminPassword": {
          "type": "securestring"
      }
  },
  "variables": {
    "storageAccountName": "[concat('stor567', uniqueString(resourceGroup().id))]",
    "storageAccountType": "Standard_LRS",
    "vmWindowsOSVersion": "2016-Datacenter",
    "vnetPrefix": "10.0.0.0/16",
    "vnetSubnet1Name": "Subnet-1",
    "vnetSubnet1Prefix": "10.0.0.0/24",
    "nicVnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vnet')]",
    "nicSubnetRef": "[concat(variables('nicVnetID'), '/subnets/', variables('vnetSubnet1Name'))]",
    "vmImagePublisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
    "vmImageOffer": "WindowsServer",
    "vmVmSize": "Standard_DS1_v2",
    "vmVnetID": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vnet')]",
    "vmSubnetRef": "[concat(variables('vmVnetID'), '/subnets/', variables('vnetSubnet1Name'))]",
    "vmStorageAccountContainerName": "vhds"
  },
  "resources": [
      {
          "name": "[variables('storageAccountName')]",
          "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
          "dependsOn": [ ],
        "properties": {
          "accountType": "[variables('storageAccountType')]"
        }
      },
      {
          "name": "vnet",
          "type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
          "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
          "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
          "dependsOn": [ ],
          "tags": {
              "displayName": "vnet"
          },
          "properties": {
              "addressSpace": {
                  "addressPrefixes": [
                      "[variables('vnetPrefix')]"
                  ]
              },
              "subnets": [
                  {
                      "name": "[variables('vnetSubnet1Name')]",
                      "properties": {
                          "addressPrefix": "[variables('vnetSubnet1Prefix')]"
                      }
                  }
              ]
          }
      },
    {
      "name": "[concat('NIC',copyindex())]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "nicLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfVMs')]"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2016-03-30",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'vnet')]"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "nic"
      },
      "properties": {
        "ipConfigurations": [
          {
            "name": "ipconfig1",
            "properties": {
              "privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
              "subnet": {
                "id": "[variables('nicSubnetRef')]"
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "[concat('VM',copyindex())]",
      "type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
      "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
      "copy": {
        "name": "virtualMachineLoop",
        "count": "[parameters('numberOfVMs')]"
      },
      "apiVersion": "2015-06-15",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName'))]",
        "nicLoop"
      ],
      "tags": {
        "displayName": "vm"
      },
      "properties": {
        "hardwareProfile": {
          "vmSize": "[variables('vmVmSize')]"
        },
        "osProfile": {
          "computerName": "[concat('VM',copyindex())]",
          "adminUsername": "[parameters('vmAdminUsername')]",
          "adminPassword": "[parameters('vmAdminPassword')]"
        },
        "storageProfile": {
          "imageReference": {
            "publisher": "[variables('vmImagePublisher')]",
            "offer": "[variables('vmImageOffer')]",
            "sku": "[variables('vmWindowsOSVersion')]",
            "version": "latest"
          },
          "osDisk": {
            "name": "vmOSDisk",
            "vhd": {
              "uri": "[concat(reference(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', variables('storageAccountName')), '2016-01-01').primaryEndpoints.blob, variables('vmStorageAccountContainerName'), '/', 'VM',copyIndex(),'-','OSdisk.vhd')]"
            },
            "caching": "ReadWrite",
            "createOption": "FromImage"
          }
        },
        "networkProfile": {
          "networkInterfaces": [
            {
              "id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', concat('NIC',copyindex()))]"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }],
  "outputs": {}
}
```

However, I'm struggling to integrate using of password as unique secrets from Key Vault in that template. If I use example from official documentation [Reference a secret with static id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-a-secret-with-static-id) VMs with secret1 for each VM will be created. And I can’t wrap [Reference a secret with dynamic id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-keyvault-parameter#reference-a-secret-with-static-id) into nested template because that would deploy my copied VMs again and again for the each number of VMs I would like to deploy. Please help me understand, how this challenge can be solved?

Comment: why cant you do that with a nested template and copyloop? i struggle to understand

Comment: Because it just wouldn't deploy.
http://pastebin.com/w2p8n0te
Suppose I want to create 2 VMs (for example), but that nested is defined as copy in the main template, so ARM tries to deploy that 2 VMs then immediately deploy them again, but with another secret.
Here is the main template azuredeploy.json:
http://pastebin.com/tSyPp8fH
Here is the nested template nestedTemplate.json:
http://pastebin.com/FTrbmrnc

Comment: I think I finally got what you are saying and this case looks interesting. I'll try to create a solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Links: [Parent](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/multiple-vm-keyvault) and [Nested](https://github.com/4c74356b41/armotron/blob/master/multiple-vm-keyvault-nested).
I'm not sure if that's what you meant (because i still think that i struggle to understand your problem).

These templates allow to deploy variable amount of vm's and use different keyvault keys as passwords for those. Example:

2 Windows VM's with one secret and 3 Ubuntu VM's with another
1 Windows VM with one secret and 4 Ubuntu VM's with another

You can easily extend that to other images, like centos.
As you can probably see after looking at the templates I'm using `arrays` and `copyindex()` to feed proper values where they belong.

Tell me if that's not what you are after. Be careful when using those, github raw links use some form of caching, so deploying from github might not work for you with errors, in that case just use the links I've provided (NOT RAW) to copy to local machine and upload to some service like pastebin, and deploy from there.

Comment: What you did is kind of not what I was looking for, but your approach to give nested template separate count and feed it arrays is what I needed. As always, your answers have been the most helpful. I believe, you deserve MVP. There are a couple issues with your template, a couple of typos in the nested template, and if you deploy multiple counts of nested templates they might conflict with each other (VNETs and Availability sets trying to overwrite each other settings), so it might be better to move VNETs and Availability sets to the parent template. But I'm 100% happy with it!

Comment: typos? can you please point them out? I've deployed that template and it worked flawlessly, did you follow my advice about the github and its caching? @Max and thanks for the kind words ;)

Comment: Yes, I've encountered GitHub caching problem myself. Sometimes it would give ARM new version instantly, and sometimes it wouldn't give even newly generated files for 5 minutes.
In your nested template I had to add comma at the line 10,
had to replace line 45 and 50 with:
`"virtualNetworkName": "concat[parameters("prefix"), 'myVNET']",`
`"availabilitySetName": "concat[parameters("prefix"), 'myAvSet']",`
Otherwise it wouldn't deploy from VS for me.

Comment: somehow comma was missing, but lines 45 and 50 were exactly how you say. thanks! @Max